# How to change the style of multiple jQuery selected objects without using a for loop?

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, textarea

Basically, I a trying to change the height of a textarea based on how many lines it has which is kind of irrelevant to the question, but here is the coding of adding event listeners to every textarea without using a for loop:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(event) {
    this.style.height = Math.floor(this.scrollHeight / 11) + '.1em';
});
```

And here is my for loop:

```
for (i=0; i<$('textarea').length; i++) {
    $('textarea')[i].style.height = Math.floor($('textarea')[i].scrollHeight / 11) + '.1em';
}
```

The for loop works perfectly, but just for the sake of clean and efficient coding I would like for it to look more like the first coding without a for loop being needed.

Also, a note that all of this inside a if document is ready function.

Comment: Use a loop. That's what loops are for. It impossible to accomplish this without one. You might consider a `.each` loop, as below, but it's *still* a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try `each()` method:

```
$('textarea').each(function(){
     $(this).css('height', Math.floor(this.scrollHeight / 11) + '.1em')
})
```

[jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 3):

I was a bit late I agree with top answer! +1

```
$('textarea').each(function(ele){
  ele.style.height = Math.floor(ele.scrollHeight / 11) + '.1em';
}};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(event) {

    // change height of all textarea including current
    $('textarea').css('height', Math.floor(this.scrollHeight / 11) + '.1em');

    // But using this like following
    // will change height of current textarea

    // $(this).css('height', Math.floor(this.scrollHeight / 11) + '.1em');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('textarea').keyup(function() {

      $("textarea").each(function () {
        this.height(Math.floor(this.scrollHeight / 11) + '.1em')

      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to enhance the answer by thecodeparadox.

```
var jq_textarea = $('textarea');
jq_textarea.keyup(function(event) {
    jq_textarea.css('height', Math.floor(this.scrollHeight / 11) + '.1em');
});
```

Basically it would save you from a DOM traversal on each key stroke.